# When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself).

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3

Here is my following code:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 0, width:
      tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height))
    headerLabel.font = UIFont().robotoMedium(withFontSize: 10)
    headerLabel.textColor = CustomColor.lightGrey.color
    headerLabel.text = "Travel Shops"
    headerLabel.sizeToFit()
    headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)
    headerLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    headerLabel.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: tableView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    headerLabel.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: tableView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    headerLabel.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.topLayoutGuide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    headerLabel.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 131))
    return headerView
  }
```

But the application crashes with the following:

**When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`headerLabel` is child view of `headerView` and `headerView` is child of `TableView` in the hierarchy that is why this message is shown you need add the constraints to `headerView` which is the `headerLabel.superView`  instead of UITableView which is `headerLabel.superView.superView`

**Change your code**

```
    headerLabel.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: headerView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    headerLabel.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: headerView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    headerLabel.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.topLayoutGuide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    headerLabel.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 131))
```

**by this one**

```
    headerLabel.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: tableView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    headerLabel.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: headerView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    headerLabel.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: headerView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    headerLabel.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 131))
```

Hope this helps